# using string to select object value within an array

Tags: c#

Currently struggling with a issue. 
I have 30 objects in an array. data[], in each object there is 24 hours.
"Hour00", "Hour01" and so on. I want to iterate through these hours. if(data[i].Hour00 > something) 
But it seems like I cant increment this in an easy way. I tried with the code below but it doesn't allow me to use the string "b" to define which of the hours I want to extract.

```
for(int k = 0; k < 24; k++)
{
    string b = "Hour00";
    if(data[i].b > 20){
        *Something happens*

}
```

also tried:

```
for(int k = 0; k < 24; k++)
{
    if(data[i].Hour(k) > 20){
        *Something happens*

}
```

Comment: Can you _edit_ your question to show us the definition of `data`? What is it an array **of**?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand but sounds like you'd be better off having a dictionary structure where the key is `Hour00`, `Hour01`... and the value is an int. Then you can loop through that much more easily than iterating through all properties and dynamically adding the variable name.

Comment: Dayum... this is some really bad understanding of how C# works (and most languages)... but I suggest you look into "C# Reflection"

Comment: Why don't you use an `int`, `TimeSpan` or `DateTime` property instead of this string mess?

Comment: @RiceNor : is "Hour00", "Hour01" and so on is limited to 24?

Comment: @keyboardP - OP can't because it is clear that there is already a class/struct with `HourXX` props.

Comment: @NikhilVartak - Yes but OP may have access to that class and therefore design it in a more suitable way.

Comment: Sorry for my bad writing, 
I cant change how the design is setup sadly.. 
I need the values which are in data[k].hour00, data[k].hour01 and so on.   k represents the day I need the data for, and I need to check every hour if the value has gone over 20 or not.  
The values for XX in HourXX is from 00 to 23

Comment: kindly show your class design

Comment: public class DataModel{
             public double Hour00;
             public double Hour01;
             public double Hour02;
             public double Hour03;
             public double Hour04;
             public double Hour05;
                   //And so on until 23
}
When I get information from the server it populates an array of 30 days. For example if we want to extract day four's, 14.00 data:   data[4].Hour14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a sample class `Item`

```
public class Item
{
    public int Hour0 { get;set;}
    public int Hour1 { get;set;}
    public int Hour2 { get;set;}
}
```

Using reflection you could iterate over `HourXX` props as:

```
var item = new Item { Hour0 = 10, Hour1 = 15, Hour2 = 20 };

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    var hourPropValue = typeof(Item).GetProperty("Hour" + i).GetValue(item);
    // Conditional code here
}
```

Comment: Helped alot but it wont let me get out the specific data.
The Array is like this:
Day 1:
{
Data[0].Hour00
Data[0].Hour01
Data[0].Hour02 etc.


The next day:
Data[1].Hour00
Data[1].Hour01
Data[1].Hour02 
Data[1].Hour03    }

 and so on.
The iterations of days is easy to handle but the hourXX aint.

Comment: What is shown above is a iteration for hours. You need outer loop for days. That's it. What is difficult to imagine is why you have such design. There are 30 days 24 hours each. Why would each hour contain a different value that you need `if` conditions. Not sure what code you are writing for! `if` condition would make sense if you had only one property that represented hour value.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil figured it out. 
And thanks for being patient with my formulation of the question. New to this.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your comment, now as far as I understand. Assuming that the properties Hour00..Hour23 holding integer values:

```
int day = DateTime.Today.Day;
for (int i=0; i<24; i++){
  int value = data[day].GetType().GetProperty(string.Format("Hour{0:00}",i)).GetValue(data[day], null);
}
```

Comment: " 30 objects in an array. data[], in each object there is 24 hours. "Hour00", "Hour01" and so on"  i think the loop will be on array which has  class/struct with HourXX

Comment: true, I need to loop through Hour01 Hour02 and so on. if we are on the second this month it would be data[2].HourXX

Comment: Added above @RiceNor

Comment: Error: (Cannot implicitly convert type "object" to "int" an explicit conversion exists. are you missing a cast?)